# R files in capital and lowercase. Difference?

Tags: r, rstudio, file-extension

Someone gave me some "R" files.  Some of them are saved with a capital "R" extension, i.e. ".R", and some are saved with a lowercase extension, i.e. ".r".

I can open the lowercase ones fine, but the uppercase ones say that permission is denied?

My questions:
-  What is a way around this?  I cannot contact him to get the original files.
-  What is the fundamental difference between saving in ".R" and ".r"?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using an `R` program to open them? (e.g., RStudio)

Comment: Yes, I am using RStudio

Comment: I Rstudio, Sorting the files (in file panel) by type of file (icon column) puts .r and .R in very different places. Whats up with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no difference. If you are getting permission denied on reading any files, then you need to change the permissions so you can read them.

If you are on unix, you can use the following command assuming you own the files.

```
chmod u+r <filename>
```